# canvas.move not working correctly

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making A python game and the canvas.move function is not working properly.
The Function below is what I am trying to use to move the enemy to the player:

```
def AttackPlayer(self):
    Enemy.canvas.move(Enemy.man,self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[0],self.canvas.coords(Man1.man)[1])
    root.after(400,self.AttackPlayer)
```

I want this function to move the enemy to the player but it just moves the enemy to the player then moves the enemy to the edge of the screen. The enemy stays at the edge of the screen forever.

I already know this function when working correctly will just snap the enemy on to the player so do not let me know.

Comment: Are you aware that the values given to move are _added_ to the existing coordinates, rather than moving the item _to_ the new coordinates?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: How would I move the Enemy to specific coordinates

Comment: Compute the difference between the coordinates you want to go to and the coordinates you're at, and pass that value to `move()`.